# objective-c ichat chat program control

Tags: objective-c, controls, skype, ichat

Is it possible to have an objective-c application send and receive iChat messages without iChat? NOT with applescript. I also want to do this to skype, mail, etc.

Is any of this possible? I need this to be in objective-c, not applescript, so it all needs to be within objective-c. If so, can someone post examples, websites, additional info?

Thanks,
Elijah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [Instant Message Framework](http://developer.apple.com/leopard/overview/imframework.html) that allow to use iChat inside your applications. It even allows to use iChat Theater from your applications.

Answer (score 1):

I would hazard a guess that iChat isn't providing any sort of public API for you to use.  That said, you can use AppleScript from Cocoa - check out the [NSAppleScript documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Yes, I would have to agree. How about AIM, I think that has an API. I will try that out as well.

Comment: @Elijah, if you just want to avoid using the iChat application itself, you can just use any number of IM libraries - check out libpurple: http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple

Comment: GREAT!! thanks! Now, are there lists of other libraries that can mimic other applications like mail, or itunes?

Comment: @Elijah, yes.  There are libraries to do almost anything you can imagine.

Comment: Can you post a website that has alot of libraries on it so I can browse through them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.  Check out [Adium](http://adium.im/).